# Cannot find Microsoft Edge binary

Tags: webdrivermanager-java

Try to start a selenium test with the edge driver and get an exception

Everything is working fine with firefox and chrome, but I couldn't manage it to start edge (Version 77.0.223.0 (Official build) dev (64-bit)).

This is my test class

```
class EdgeTest {
  private static String binaryPath;
  private WebDriver driver;

  @BeforeEach
  public void setupTest() {
    WebDriverManager.edgedriver().setup();
    binaryPath = WebDriverManager.edgedriver().getBinaryPath();
    WebDriverManager.edgedriver().browserPath("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge Dev\\Application\\msedge.exe\")");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", binaryPath);
    driver = new EdgeDriver();
  }

  @After
  public void teardown() {
    if (driver != null) {
      driver.quit();
    }
  }

  @Test
  public void test() {
    // Your test code here. For example:
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    driver.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page");
  }
```

This is the exception I get:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot find Microsoft Edge binary
Build info: version: '3.141.0', revision: '2ecb7d9a', time: '2018-10-31T20:09:30'
System info: host: 'IRVING', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_212'
Driver info: driver.version: EdgeDriver
remote stacktrace: Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x00007FF7845DD422+1823778]
    Ordinal0 [0x00007FF7845457B2+1202098]
```

And logs

```
14:46:46.411 [main] DEBUG i.g.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - Edge Dev (based on Chromium) version 77 found
14:46:46.415 [main] DEBUG i.g.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - Driver for edge77 not found in local properties
14:46:46.668 [main] DEBUG i.g.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - The driver version for Microsoft Edge 77 is unknown ... trying with latest
14:46:46.669 [main] DEBUG i.g.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - Reading https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/ to find out the latest version of Edge driver
14:46:47.050 [main] INFO  i.g.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - Latest version of Edge driver is 77.0.229.0
14:46:47.060 [main] INFO  io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.Downloader - Using binary driver previously downloaded
14:46:47.060 [main] INFO  i.g.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - Exporting webdriver.edge.driver as C:\Users\cseegraef\.m2\repository\webdriver\edgedriver\win64\x64\77.0.229.0\msedgedriver.exe
Previous : 1.8.0_212-b03
Starting MSEdgeDriver 77.0.229.0 (219d9c8b098bc5511828863cd68c4e880c69814b) on port 46356
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by the WebDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
```

Thanks for any help or information.

Comment: ok, found the solution on my own.... just had to add the path to edgeDev my enviroment variables on my computer...